# Django: Como impedir conflitos de campos de data no admin

Tags: python, django, django-2.0, django-admin

Em um cadastro de uma `Vaga` dentro do admin do django eu tenho dois campos: `data_inicio` e `data_fim`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu Gostaria que não fosse possível colocar uma `data_fim` inferior a `data_inicio`, e não sei como isso pode ser feito no admin do django. O código do admin da vaga encontra-se assim:

```py
@admin.register(Vaga)
class VagaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('titulo', 'data_inicio', 'data_fim')
```

Se alguém tiver uma noção de como isso possa ser feito, ou algum link que possa ajudar, eu ficaria grato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar um form com a validação

### Modifique o VagaAdmin

```
@admin.register(Vaga)
class VagaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = VagaForm
    list_display = ('titulo', 'data_inicio', 'data_fim')
```

### Crie o Form com a validação

```
class VagaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vaga

    def clean(self):
        data_inicio = self.cleaned_data.get('data_inicio')
        data_fim = self.cleaned_data.get('data_fim')
        if data_inicio > data_fim:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Data de início posterior a data fim")
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Oi paulo, eu cheguei em uma solução parecida mais cedo, porém no class Meta eu adicionei  o Fields. Vou marcar a resposta como solução.